# Memoir Class Table of Contents creates its own heading

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir

I'm using the Memoir class, and trying to create a table of contents. I've shopped around on few questions here, and by now I have managed to get all my unnumbered sections/subsections to show up.
However, using \tableofcontents seems to create a section or chapter of its own, such that every section in the memoir seems to be a subsection of "contents", like so

```
 Contents.............................. 1
       Introduction.................... 2
       Dummy Section................... 2
       Dummy Subsection 1.............. 2
       Dummy Subsection 2.............. 2
```

And so on. Additionally, every paged is now headed with "CONTENTS" in the right page header. Both issues can be seen in the attached picture.

My code is as follows;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\title{title}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\section{Abstract}
Blablabla
\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}
Blablabla

\section{Dummy Section}
Blablabla


\subsection{First Dummy Subsection}
BlablablaBlablablaBlablabla


\subsection{Second Dummy Subsection}
BlablablaBlablablaBlablablaBlablabla


\section{Results}
BlablablaBlablabla

\end{document}
```

[image: Sections being delegated to subsections of 'Contents']

Comment: Use `tableofcontents*` to remove it from the contents list.

Comment: This removes it from the contents list, but it remains as a page header throughout the document.

Comment: `memoir` isn't really designed to be used without `\chapters`. There is an `article` class option which makes `\chapter` into the equivalent of `\section`. This should probably solve your problem, but if you're writing an article there are better classes to consider I think.

Comment: Yes, I was using a template (provided by my educational institute) which used the memoir class. I've since resorted to simply using <Report> which works excellently.

Comment: `memoir` also covers the `report` class. If in your MWE you just change `{memoir}` to `{report}` then you will get the problem you reported. You must have done something more than that which could be applied to your `memoir` document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memoir` class is designed as a replacement for the `book` class, not as a general purpose document class. Because of this, it is designed on the model that the document will have `\chapter` divisions. This is the source of the problem you are seeing: the `\tableofcontents` creates an unnumbered `\chapter` and since you have no `\chapter` commands in the rest of the document, all of your `\section` commands are interpreted as part of that chapter.

The `memoir` class has an `[article]` document class option which makes `\chapter` behave like `\section`, which would probably solve your immediate problem (you would then make all your `\section` commands `\chapter` but they would not begin a new page).

Alternatively, if you're writing a document that isn't designed to have `\chapter` divisions then use a more appropriate document class such as `article`.